# How to remove a Google AdWords campaign using scripts?

Tags: google-ads

[`AdWordsApp.​Campaign`](https://developers.google.com/adwords/scripts/docs/reference/adwordsapp/adwordsapp_campaign) does not provide a method `remove`, `delete` or anything similar that could be used to delete a campaign.

How to remove a Google AdWords campaign using scripts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You set the campaign status to `REMOVED` and call `mutate` on the CampaignService.  The [documentation](https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/reference/v201710/CampaignService#mutate) says:

> ### mutate
>
> Adds, updates, or removes campaigns.
>
> > Note: [CampaignOperation](https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/reference/v201710/CampaignService.CampaignOperation.html) does not support the REMOVE operator. To remove a campaign, set its [status](https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/reference/v201710/CampaignService.Campaign.html#status) to REMOVED